# Can't load a .dll with System.load(path);

Tags: java, dll

I made a Java OCR program using the AspriseOCR.
It requires a .dll called AspriseOCR.dll, I copied the dll to C:/Windows/System32/
But when I use

```
System.load("C:/Windows/System32/AspriseOCR.dll");
```

I still get a UnsatisfiedLinkError.

I've spent the last 2 days searching for a solution to my problem, but I couldn't find anything  that works.

---

Okay everyone, it works now. Turns out I also had to make a 32-bit version!
If anyone ever needs help with the OCR Engine from Asprise, pm and I'll try to help you!

Comment: Try copying `AspriseOCR.dll` to the working directory and use `loadLibrary("AspriseOCR")` instead.

Comment: @oldrinb, I don't know why... but your tip made me do it. I just made a runnable jar from Eclipse, put the jar in a directory with the .dll and then made a program that does this: java -Xmx1024m -jar OCR.jar And now it works!

Comment: @oldrinb 
`System.loadLibrary("files/AspriseOCR")` still requires me to put the dll in System32 for some reason. Any ideas on how to change this?

Comment: `loadLibrary` takes the library name, not a path.

Comment: @oldrinb  You should enter that as an answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson although it solves the apparent issue, I don't have an explanation for why it didn't work as it was before... why would I post an inadequate incomplete answer? :-)

Comment: YMMV, but I think your 1st & 3rd comments together represent an answer.

Comment: Is the UnsatisfiedLinkError thrown when you call `System.load` or when you try to access dll functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load libraries, such as DLLs, you should use

```
    System.loadLibrary("libname");
```

Where `"libname"` is the *name* of the library. You do not include the extension of the file it is stored in, or the full path to the file. For your case, you would probably call

```
    System.loadLibrary("AspriseOCR");
```

to load the library you are using.

Because `loadLibrary` takes a library name for an argument, not a file, you must be careful where you place the .dll. Normally, you could include it in the working directory of the application, or in a native folder such as System32. If you must put it somewhere else, be sure to appropriately set `java.libary.path`. For example, if the .dll is in the folder "libraries", you should launch java with the argument

```
    -Djava.library.path=libraries
```

Comment: '-Djava.library.path=libraries' won't work because it's not recognised for some reason.