# Loading DLL from Classpath

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load a DLL in Java from the Classpath. I have a folder called 'lib' that is on the Classpath, but it's actual location is unknown. The DLL resides in `lib/dll/(x64|win32)/library.dll`. I can successfully load the DLL using this line, but only if the 'lib' folder is in the current working directory:

```
System.load(new File("lib\\dll\\" + dllFolder + "\\library.dll").getAbsolutePath());
```

Unfortunately, our use case is such that it's just not possible to have the folder always in the current working directory. How can I go about loading the DLL from the Classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `-Djava.library.path=<path to library root>` as an argument when your application starts up.

See  [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334214/cant-load-a-dll-with-system-loadpath)

Note the differences between calling `System.load(java.lang.String)` vs `System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String)`.

Comment: This worked. May not be the way we end up going, but it's definitely a solution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the CLASSPATH variable, search if your DLL exists in one of the 'lib' folder listed in the variable. You then should be able to make a complete path name.